# Frameworks vs. Aplicación por Capas

Tags: diseño, arquitectura

Me gustaría que me resolvieseis una duda que tengo en cuestión a la realización de una Aplicación Web por capas usando un framework. Por lo tanto:

¿Es lógico crear una aplicación por capas haciendo uso de un Framework? Es decir,
¿usar la funcionalidad de un framework y a la vez crear nuestro dentro del modelo del framework nuestro modelo de datos haciendo uso de la programación por capas: Capa de negocio, capa de persistencia, patron DAO, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al desarrollar una aplicación:

> Es recomendable trabajar en capas ya que te permite la reutilización
>   de código, facilidad para el mantenimiento, programar usando POO,
>   separación de responsabilidades, escalabilidad en tu aplicación, puedes
>   usar una arquitectura de tres capas o n-capas según la complejidad del
>   negocio.

[*Arquitectura de aplicaciones de .NET: Diseño de aplicaciones y servicios*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms954595.aspx)

[*Arquitectura N-Capas DDD .NET 4.0*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2010/03/11/nuestro-nuevo-libro-guia-de-arquitectura-n-capas-ddd-net-4-0-y-aplicacion-ejemplo-en-disponibles-para-download-en-msdn-y-codeplex/)

Sobre los Framework si te refieres a los ORM's puedes usar entre los mas conocidos: Entity Framework, NHibernate:

> Con un ORM podemos mapear nuestro modelo de datos a nuestros objetos
>   y estructura de clases de nuestra aplicación, logrando con esto
>   resolver el acceso y persistencia de datos sin mucho esfuerzo y poder
>   enfocarnos en lo que verdaderamente nos importa, el dominio del
>   negocio.

[*Entity Framework (EF) Documentation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712907(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Lo usual es que una app por capas se apoye en un framework que se lo facilite. Por ejemplo:

- ASP.NET + MVC 5 + WCF
- Java -» J2EE + Spring + ORM

Comment: MVC es un patrón de diseño que va implementado en la capa de presentación, no es un framework.

Comment: Si es una aplicacion por capas, es muy probable (al menos asi lo veo yo, que ocupe Entity Framework, me parece una respuesta valida si se agregan ejemplos de frameworks que se pudieran utilizar.